# Filtering realm objects with Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3, realm, swift4

I have the following object model:

```
class Work: Object {
@objc dynamic var id = 0
@objc dynamic var firstName: String? = nil
@objc dynamic var lastName: String? = nil
@objc dynamic var jobDesc: String? = nil
@objc dynamic var avatar: String? = nil
@objc dynamic var isInvited = 0
@objc dynamic var typeContact = 0
override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "id"
}
```

So im looking to get the selected work with all the lines, but only with isInvited which are 1. Is this possible in realm, to filter lists in retrieved objects?

Comment: try using a predicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - realm filter

```
let realm = try! Realm()
let Works = realm.objects(Work.self).filter("isInvited == 1")
```

For more details refer realm documentation 
https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/